# DESeq2: Error in checkFullRank(modelMatrix)

Tags: r, rna-seq

I want to build a DEseq2 model matrix using this coldata but it shows this error:

> Error in checkFullRank(modelMatrix) :
> the model matrix is not full rank, so the model cannot be fit as specified.
> Levels or combinations of levels without any samples have resulted in
> column(s) of zeros in the model matrix.
> Please read the vignette section 'Model matrix not full rank':
> vignette('DESeq2')

My code:

```
deseqData_2<-DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = tot_genes, colData = tot_clinic, design = ~condition + viral_load + condition:viral_load)
```

My colData:

```
structure(list(age = c("64", "30", "47", "67", "62", "52", "39", 
"59", "60", "71", "64", "45", "42", "53", "86", "50", "65", "34", 
"67", "61", "60", "23", "61", "33", "33", "24", "51", "25", "82", 
"72", "78", "72", "61", "68", "34", "75", "55", "46", "27", "31", 
"51", "46", "51", "71", "88", "71", "41", "51", "53", "52", "80", 
"37", "51", "41", "64", "28", "37", "62", "78", "19", "76", "23", 
"30", "63", "75", "65", "21", "51", "72", "66", "57", "83", "56", 
"49", "44", "49", "57", "34", "57", "46", "26", "69", "56", "30", 
"58", "77", "33", "53", "56", "32", "44", "28", "46", "28", "43", 
"72", "54", "22", "64", "43", "59", "81", "54", "65", "67", "80", 
"43", "49", "53", "90+", "38", "70", "38", "54", "66", "67", 
"36", "56", "41", "20", "51", "66", "35", "90+", "47", "35", 
"27", "90+", "29", "51", "50", "28", "30", "27", "48", "64", 
"80", "52", "44", "90+", "41", "46", "63", "76", "30", "29", 
"41", "53", "20", "39", "25", "72", "27", "30", "82", "87", "56", 
"70", "66", "72", "50", "49", "56", "50", "52", "75", "90+", 
"82", "30", "83", "21", "45", "64", "48", "76", "37", "90+", 
"50", "48", "90+", "40", "31", "22", "61", "24", "67", "37", 
"51", "83", "39", "41", "48", "26", "79", "62", "76", "44", "57", 
"72", "59", "60", "76", "32", "66", "65", "33", "72", "12", "51", 
"80", "45", "57", "57", "47", "86", "29", "33", "43", "31", "78", 
"79", "90+", "81", "21", "71", "82", "41", "35", "58", "75", 
"77", "53", "70", "41", "59", "43", "22", "55", "67", "57", "71", 
"62", "64", "16", "58", "37", "37", "56", "79", "49", "63", "58", 
"90+", "79", "70", "35", "62", "57", "36", "41", "63", "61", 
"35", "57", "52", "45", "39", "30", "64", "57", "53", "57", "72", 
"23", "88", "90+", "90+", "60", "40", "90+", "80", "19", "77", 
"76", "53", "58", "72", "71", "36", "49", "76", "70", "28", "32", 
"84", "90+", "25", "70", "24", "48", "28", "40", "70", "58", 
"70", "89", "89", "52", "71", "48", "66", "65", "87", "78", "90+", 
"39", "38", "58", "56", "85", "47", "51", "58", "42", "78", "56", 
"39", "50", "63", "64", "22", "71", "80", "32", "85", "56", "71", 
"61", "50", "28", "40", "84", "24", "60", "28", "22", "90+", 
"71", "74", "90+", "81", "86", "90+", "82", "90+", "85", "70", 
"90+", "85", "54", "58", "62", "78", "90+", "39", "45", "57", 
"28", "85", "90+", "49", "55", "78", "77", "59", "47", "58", 
"63", "55", "78", "18", "44", "54", "41", "33", "2", "37", "72", 
"48", "75", "58", "82", "78", "81", "57", "74", "54", "50", "37", 
"38", "45", "78", "78", "65", "42", "35", "35", "39", "48", "42", 
"53", "61", "51", "26", "29", "47", "66", "51", "45", "13", "12", 
"35", "64", "23", "60", "76", "90+", "29", "65", "22", "30", 
"79", "22", "63", "74", "38", "45", "51", "55", "23", "52", "71", 
"66", "40", "22", "63", "66", "30", "55", "72", "44", "52", "43", 
"54", "54", "30", "20", "24", "41", "39", "46", "47", "41", "22", 
"59", "49", "75", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "78", "78", "78", "78", "78", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "41", "41"
), gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "not collected", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "not collected", 
"M", "F", "F", "not collected", "F", "F", "not collected", "not collected", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "not collected", "F", "F", "M", 
"not collected", "F", "not collected", "not collected", "not collected", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "not collected", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "not collected", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "not collected", "F", 
"not collected", "not collected", "F", "F", "M", "F", "not collected", 
"not collected", "not collected", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "not collected", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "not collected", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "not collected", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "not collected", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "not collected", "not collected", "not collected", 
"M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "not collected", "not collected", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "not collected", "M", "not collected", 
"F", "F", "M", "not collected", "F", "F", "not collected", "F", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "not collected", "M", 
"F", "M", "not collected", "not collected", "F", "F", "M", "not collected", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "not collected", "F", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F"), viral_load = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"high", "low", "medium"), class = "factor"), condition = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("healthy", "COVID-19", "fluA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("POS_001", 
"POS_002", "POS_003", "POS_004", "POS_005", "POS_006", "POS_007", 
"POS_008", "POS_009", "POS_010", "POS_011", "POS_012", "POS_013", 
"POS_014", "POS_015", "POS_016", "POS_017", "POS_018", "POS_019", 
"POS_020", "POS_021", "POS_022", "POS_023", "POS_024", "POS_025", 
"POS_026", "POS_027", "POS_028", "POS_029", "POS_030", "POS_031", 
"POS_032", "POS_033", "POS_034", "POS_035", "POS_036", "POS_037", 
"POS_039", "POS_040", "POS_041", "POS_042", "POS_043", "POS_044", 
"POS_045", "POS_046", "POS_047", "POS_048", "POS_049", "POS_050", 
"POS_051", "POS_052", "POS_053", "POS_055", "POS_056", "POS_057", 
"POS_058", "POS_059", "POS_060", "POS_061", "POS_062", "POS_063", 
"POS_064", "POS_065", "POS_066", "POS_067", "POS_068", "POS_069", 
"POS_070", "POS_071", "POS_072", "POS_073", "POS_074", "POS_075", 
"POS_076", "POS_077", "POS_078", "POS_079", "POS_080", "POS_081", 
"POS_082", "POS_083", "POS_084", "POS_085", "POS_086", "POS_087", 
"POS_088", "POS_089", "POS_090", "POS_092", "POS_093", "POS_094", 
"POS_095", "POS_096", "POS_097", "POS_098", "POS_099", "POS_100", 
"POS_101", "POS_102", "POS_103", "POS_104", "POS_105", "POS_106", 
"POS_107", "POS_108", "POS_109", "POS_111", "POS_112", "POS_113", 
"POS_114", "POS_115", "POS_116", "POS_117", "POS_118", "POS_119", 
"POS_120", "POS_121", "POS_122", "POS_123", "POS_124", "POS_125", 
"POS_126", "POS_127", "POS_128", "POS_129", "POS_130", "POS_131", 
"POS_132", "POS_133", "POS_134", "POS_135", "POS_136", "POS_137", 
"POS_138", "POS_139", "POS_141", "POS_142", "POS_143", "POS_144", 
"POS_145", "POS_146", "POS_147", "POS_148", "POS_149", "POS_150", 
"POS_151", "POS_152", "POS_153", "POS_154", "POS_155", "POS_156", 
"POS_157", "POS_158", "POS_159", "POS_160", "POS_161", "POS_162", 
"POS_163", "POS_164", "POS_165", "POS_166", "POS_167", "POS_168", 
"POS_169", "POS_170", "POS_171", "POS_172", "POS_173", "POS_174", 
"POS_175", "POS_176", "POS_177", "POS_178", "POS_179", "POS_180", 
"POS_181", "POS_182", "POS_183", "POS_184", "POS_185", "POS_186", 
"POS_187", "POS_188", "POS_189", "POS_190", "POS_191", "POS_192", 
"POS_193", "POS_194", "POS_195", "POS_196", "POS_197", "POS_198", 
"POS_199", "POS_200", "POS_201", "POS_202", "POS_203", "POS_204", 
"POS_205", "POS_206", "POS_207", "POS_208", "POS_209", "POS_210", 
"POS_211", "POS_212", "POS_213", "POS_214", "POS_215", "POS_216", 
"POS_217", "POS_218", "POS_219", "POS_220", "POS_221", "POS_222", 
"POS_223", "POS_224", "POS_225", "POS_226", "POS_227", "POS_228", 
"POS_229", "POS_230", "POS_231", "POS_232", "POS_233", "POS_234", 
"POS_236", "POS_237", "POS_238", "POS_239", "POS_240", "POS_241", 
"POS_242", "POS_243", "POS_244", "POS_245", "POS_246", "POS_247", 
"POS_249", "POS_250", "POS_251", "POS_252", "POS_253", "POS_254", 
"POS_255", "POS_256", "POS_257", "POS_258", "POS_259", "POS_260", 
"POS_261", "POS_262", "POS_263", "POS_264", "POS_265", "POS_266", 
"POS_267", "POS_268", "POS_269", "POS_270", "POS_271", "POS_272", 
"POS_273", "POS_274", "POS_275", "POS_276", "POS_277", "POS_278", 
"POS_279", "POS_280", "POS_281", "POS_282", "POS_283", "POS_284", 
"POS_285", "POS_286", "POS_287", "POS_288", "POS_289", "POS_290", 
"POS_291", "POS_292", "POS_293", "POS_295", "POS_296", "POS_297", 
"POS_298", "POS_299", "POS_300", "POS_301", "POS_302", "POS_303", 
"POS_304", "POS_305", "POS_306", "POS_307", "POS_308", "POS_309", 
"POS_310", "POS_311", "POS_312", "POS_313", "POS_314", "POS_315", 
"POS_316", "POS_317", "POS_318", "POS_319", "POS_320", "POS_321", 
"POS_322", "POS_323", "POS_324", "POS_325", "POS_326", "POS_327", 
"POS_328", "POS_329", "POS_330", "POS_331", "POS_332", "POS_333", 
"POS_334", "POS_335", "POS_336", "POS_337", "POS_338", "POS_339", 
"POS_340", "POS_341", "POS_342", "POS_343", "POS_344", "POS_345", 
"POS_346", "POS_347", "POS_348", "POS_349", "POS_350", "POS_351", 
"POS_352", "POS_353", "POS_354", "POS_355", "POS_356", "POS_357", 
"POS_358", "POS_359", "POS_360", "POS_361", "POS_362", "POS_363", 
"POS_364", "POS_365", "POS_366", "POS_367", "POS_368", "POS_369", 
"POS_370", "POS_371", "POS_372", "POS_373", "POS_374", "POS_375", 
"POS_376", "POS_377", "POS_378", "POS_379", "POS_380", "POS_381", 
"POS_382", "POS_383", "POS_384", "POS_385", "POS_386", "POS_387", 
"POS_388", "POS_389", "POS_390", "POS_391", "POS_392", "POS_393", 
"POS_394", "POS_395", "POS_396", "POS_397", "POS_398", "POS_399", 
"POS_400", "POS_401", "POS_402", "POS_403", "POS_404", "POS_405", 
"POS_406", "POS_407", "POS_408", "POS_409", "POS_410", "POS_411", 
"POS_412", "POS_413", "POS_414", "POS_415", "POS_416", "POS_417", 
"POS_418", "POS_419", "POS_420", "POS_421", "NEG_001", "NEG_002", 
"NEG_003", "NEG_004", "NEG_005", "NEG_006", "NEG_007", "NEG_008", 
"NEG_009", "NEG_010", "NEG_011", "NEG_012", "NEG_013", "NEG_014", 
"NEG_016", "NEG_018", "NEG_019", "NEG_020", "NEG_021", "NEG_022", 
"NEG_023", "NEG_024", "NEG_025", "NEG_026", "NEG_027", "NEG_028", 
"NEG_030", "NEG_031", "NEG_032", "NEG_035", "NEG_036", "NEG_037", 
"NEG_038", "NEG_039", "NEG_040", "NEG_042", "NEG_043", "NEG_046", 
"NEG_047", "NEG_048", "NEG_049", "NEG_050", "NEG_051", "NEG_052", 
"NEG_054", "NEG_055", "NEG_056", "NEG_057", "NEG_058", "NEG_059", 
"NEG_060", "NEG_062", "NEG_063", "NEG_065", "f7201_AGGTCATCAATC", 
"f7201_TGCTATCGGTTA", "f7201_CCTCATTGTTTG", "f7201_GTATTTAACGAA", 
"f7201_CGAATCCATCCC", "f7201_CTTTTAATAGCT", "f7201_CAGACATGTTCA", 
"f7201_ACCATCAAAGGT", "f7201_GTCGTCAAAGGG", "f7201_TGCAAGGTGGAG", 
"f7201_GTGCACGGCGTA", "f7201_GTAGCGTAGTCA", "f7201_AGGCTGTTTGGT", 
"f7201_CCATAGGGGTCT", "f7201_CCCGCGCTTGTA", "f7201_GTACGTTGGCAA", 
"f7201_GGTAAAGTGTGC", "f7201_ACATAATGGTTG", "f7201_GTTATATCGTTT", 
"f7202_ATTAAATAGCGG", "f7202_TTCCTCGCCGTT", "f7202_GTCACCTTTTAC", 
"f7202_TATACCCTATTG", "f7202_TATACCCTATTC", "f7202_CCCAGGCTCTGG", 
"f7202_TCTTGTTGATCT", "f7202_TATACCCTATTA", "f7202_TACAGCGTTCAC", 
"f7202_TTAGGAGGTCAG", "f7202_CGAGTGCCATTC", "f7203_CGCGTTGCTATG", 
"f7203_AAACCGGTAGTG", "f7203_CATGAATGTCGT", "f7203_CACTTACGGAAG", 
"f7203_CCACATAACAGT", "f7203_GCCCAATCCAGT", "f7203_CAGCACACCAAT", 
"f7203_CATGCCCCGCTT", "f7203_TCCACTCACTAG", "f7203_TACGAAATCGTA", 
"f7203_ACGTCTTTGGCG", "f7203_CCGTCCCAGCAG", "f7203_CGGTTGCCCCTT", 
"f7203_GTCTATCACGAT", "f7203_CGCCGTCGGTTA", "f7203_CTTTCATACTCA", 
"f7203_TATCTTCTATCA", "f7203_TTTGTGCTCCAC", "f7203_GGCCGTACCTGT", 
"f7203_CGATTCACTTAC", "f7203_TGCAAGATACTT", "f7203_CCCCTTCATCTG", 
"f7203_TTTGTGCTCCCC", "f7204_ATCCCACGGTAA", "f7204_CGATTCGTCTGC", 
"f7204_CTATGGGTATTA", "f7204_GCGTTTCACGAA", "f7204_CGTCCACGCGCT", 
"f7204_CTTGTGATGTTC", "f7204_ATCTCGGGCTAG", "f7204_GCCAGTTTTACG", 
"f7204_CCCGCTTCACCC", "f7204_CGACAGTCACGG", "f7204_CGTGAGTGCTAA", 
"f7204_CGTGAGTGCTAC", "f7204_CGTGAGTGCTAG", "f7204_CGTGAGTGCTAT", 
"f7204_GGCGCGTAAACG", "f7204_TATAATTACTCC", "f7204_TGTTGCGACACG", 
"f7801_AGTGGGTATCGT", "f7801_TAGGGTCGTCAG", "f7801_GTAGTGTCGTGG", 
"f7801_GCGAACGCCCCC", "f7802_ACACCGCCGTTT", "f7803_CGCATTCGCTTG", 
"f7804_CAGGTAGTAGAA", "f7902_CCCGCACGGCTA", "f7902_GTTCTTGGACTA", 
"f7903_CCCAACGTGTCC", "f7903_CAGCTTATGTGA", "f7904_GAATGTGAGGGT", 
"f8202_CGTAGGGCTGAT", "f8203_CTGATTGCAAAT", "f8204_CTACGCTGTCAA", 
"f82a02_CTGCGGTACAGC", "f82a02_TGTCGCTACGTA", "f8301_CCCACATTCCAG", 
"f8301_AAAGTCTACGAT", "f8301_CATATACGTCGT", "f8301_AGATTTCACAGA", 
"f8301_CCCGCATCTGCA", "f8301_CACGGCCTCCTC", "f8301_CGGGCGCGCATC", 
"f8301_GCTCCCCACCCT", "f8301_CCCCCAGGCCCC", "f8301_GTAAATGTTTTG", 
"f8301_CATCAGAAAGTC", "f8301_ACCTACACCTTC", "f8301_CGGGCCTCGCAG", 
"f8301_GACACTAGGTTT", "f8302_ATTTCATGCGGG", "f8302_ATCGCCTTTGCT", 
"f8302_CTAATCGATCAA", "f8302_GGCAGACGAGGA", "f8302_GCATTTCAGGCC", 
"f8302_CCGACACGCAGA", "f8302_TAAGCAGTGGTA", "f8302_TAGTTTTTAGTT", 
"f8302_CTGCCGCCACCA", "f8302_GTCTGTTAAATT", "f8302_TGTCCCCAGTCT", 
"f8302_AAAATCTTGCGA", "f8302_GGTTAGAGACTG", "f8302_GTTACCCCGAGC", 
"f8303_ACCTTTAAATCC", "f8303_CTGTGCGTCAGG", "f8303_TTAGAGTCTCTT", 
"f8303_CTCGCCGCGATG", "f8303_TACTGATCGACC", "f8303_CTATCGGGACGA", 
"f8303_GCAGGTCACGAC", "f8303_CCTATGCGCTAT", "f8303_CTCCTAGTGCCC", 
"f8303_CTCTTCCTACGC", "f8303_TTCCATAGCAGA", "f8303_GCTCCCATCGGT", 
"f8303_ACAACCTCCCAT", "f8303_GCAAACAGGAAC", "f8303_AGCCCCCCAGCC", 
"f8303_AGGAGCCATGCT", "f8303_GGAGACGACAAC", "f8303_GCTGACACCTAT", 
"f8303_ATCCATAGGGTA", "f8303_CTTGGCCAGGCC", "f8303_AGTGGAGAGAGG", 
"f8303_CTAACTAAAAAT", "f8303_CTAACTAAAAAG", "f8303_TCCTAGATTAGA", 
"f8303_ACGATGATAGTA", "f8304_CTGAGGAGTCGA", "f8304_TTATAGACTGAA", 
"f8304_GAATCCAAATAG", "f8304_TGATAGTCATAC", "f8304_CTTCTAAACAAT", 
"f8304_AGAGTCTGTTGC", "f8304_ACTATCAAGTCT", "f8304_TCAAAGTGGGGA", 
"f8304_TCAAAGTGGGGC", "f8304_TCAAAGTGGGGG", "f8304_CTCTCGCCTCCG", 
"f8304_AGCTGCCCGTTT", "f8304_TAGCCATAACCT", "f8304_CTTTTTGTGCGA", 
"f8304_CCGGTGATGGTA", "f8304_CTTGCTTCGCAT", "f8304_AGGTCCCCTGGA", 
"f8304_ACCACTCAGGGT", "f8304_CCGTGCTAGGTA", "f8304_TCAGCCCGCACT", 
"f8101_ACAACACGGCTG", "f8103_GCGAGTCCAGAT"), class = "data.frame")
        age gender viral_load condition
POS_001  64      M       high  COVID-19
POS_002  30      F     medium  COVID-19
POS_003  47      M        low  COVID-19
POS_004  67      F       high  COVID-19
POS_005  62      M        low  COVID-19
POS_006  52      F        low  COVID-19
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the relevant section of the vignette? Can you say what you did or didn't understand about it?

Comment: I tried to nest my viral_load into condition but it still shows error.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/64480/). Maybe that solves it.